# Use datetimeoffset(0) with Entity Framework Database First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first, datetimeoffset

I changed the type of several table columns from `datetime2(0)` to `datetimeoffset(0)`.

When I open the *.edmx* file and perform the "Update model from database" routine, I get the error:

> Error 40: The Type DateTimeOffset is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification. [...]

And all the classes and the dbcontext are removed.
What am I missing?

**[EDIT]**

- VS Version -> 16.4.3 SQL
- Version -> 12.0.2000.8 (azure)

**[EDIT] 2**

I "solved" by migrating to code-first

Comment: Version information, please - SQL version, VS version?

Comment: see the edit thanks